# Julia and StatsModels: print results without header line (StatsModels.DataFrameRegressionModel{...})

Tags: regression, julia

I run a linear regression with `Julia`, `GLM`, and `StatsModels` and print the results, which I include directly in the research report. This printout includes a header line with the object type, which is a distraction in the report. For example, this code:

```
using GLM, StatsModels, DataFrames

df = DataFrames.DataFrame(a = rand(10), b = rand(10))

f = fit(LinearModel, @formula(a ~ b), df)

println(f)
```

prints:

```
StatsModels.DataFrameRegressionModel{GLM.LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Array{Float64,1}},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,Base.LinAlg.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}},Array{Float64,2}}

Formula: a ~ 1 + b

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std.Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.238502  0.224529  1.06223   0.3191
b            0.333053  0.366105 0.909721   0.3896
```

I can avoid the first line by casting the object into a string and splitting at newlines:

```
f2 = split(string(f), "\n")
for i in 2:length(f2)
    println(f2[i])
end
```

and then I get:

```
Formula: a ~ 1 + b

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std.Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.238502  0.224529  1.06223   0.3191
b            0.333053  0.366105 0.909721   0.3896
```

But this is ugly and prone to errors. In the [GLM documentation of methods applied to a fit object](http://juliastats.github.io/GLM.jl/stable/index.html#Methods-applied-to-fitted-models-1), I found no methods or arguments for this. Does anyone have a cleaner way?

Comment: This is hard coded in https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsModels.jl/blob/master/src/statsmodel.jl#L122. You could create your own version of this function without this line I guess.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński: [line 121 in your link](https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsModels.jl/blob/master/src/statsmodel.jl#L121) has what I wanted: `println(coeftable(f))`. Do you want to post the answer so I accept it?

Comment: Sure :). I was not exactly sure what you needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following discussion in the comments. If you only need to get summary of coefficients of your model write:

```
julia> coeftable(f)
               Estimate Std.Error   t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    0.337666  0.205716   1.64142   0.1393
b            -0.0887478  0.378739 -0.234324   0.8206
```